# access 2013 multi value combo in table how to uncheck one value using vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I've got a lookup field/combo box (Colors) with multi-fields allowed in a table (Paint).  The drop-down shows a number of check boxes next to different colors.
It looks like:

```
☑ Red
☑ Blue
☑ Green
```

How would I locate the value 'Blue' in the field in the 1st rec and uncheck it?  I'm having a hard time referencing the Colors field in my form code:

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("Paint", dbOpenDynaset)

With rst
.MoveFirst
MsgBox ![Color].MultiSelect
End With
```

I figured that would give me a value of TRUE.  But I'm getting ***the object doesn't support this property or method***.

So, how do i reference the Color combo-box and then uncheck the appropriate value?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a "multiselect" property of the recordset you have opened.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821054.aspx) for documentation on multiselect fields.

Basically, what that says is that the value in a multiselect field is itself a recordset.  You have only obtained the recordset of the table, but not the recordset of the field.  You hopefully have an ID field in your Colors table, but if not, maybe something will be different here, but the basic idea should be the same.

You want something like this:

```
Sub test()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim childRS As Recordset
Dim valueToDelete As Long

valueToDelete = DLookup("ID", "tblColors", "Color = 'blue'")
'Obviously this depends on how your table is set up.    

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblPaint")
rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF
    Set childRS = rs!Colors.Value
    childRS.MoveFirst
    Do Until childRS.EOF
        If childRS!Value.Value = valueToDelete Then
            childRS.Delete
        End If
        childRS.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that a shot.  Just to be clear, that will uncheck the box next to Blue, not delete Blue from the list? And yes, the main table (tblPaint) has a numeric field which links to another table (tblPaintColorList) containing the colors.  tblPainColorList is IDs and Colors used to fill the drop-down.

Comment: Yes, that will uncheck the box, not delete the entry from the linked table or list of options.